# How to prevent game-client version spoofing?

Tags: security, networking, binary, protocols

Basically I have a c++ server that will use a binary protocol to talk to my client (unity game). As part of the login process I want to send the client version to the server. The server then responds saying (assuming login credentials are correct) they are okay to connect, or if the client version is outdated it returns a client version outdated.

My question is, how can I prevent people using old client versions and spoofing as the latest version. As this could potentially lead to server bugs as it is handling an outdated client thinking it is up to date.

Comment: there isn't much you can do - any dedicated attacker will be able to spoof any client side data to whatever they want. Verify communications server side and if they send outdated/invalid stuff just disconnect them

Comment: Use a "keyword" or simply a client's hash as the "magic keyword" being sent along the password. So that they'd need to spoof the hash and the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

Along passing the client version, i'd pass a hashed passphrase just to be extra safe (something they probably won't spoof so easily).

Eamples:

Client version 1.00
Passphrase "This is version 1.00" = 4fd6b272e62e04dac52cab22e0643811
So you'd receive 1.004fd6b272e62e04dac52cab22e0643811

Client version 1.1a
Passphrase "This is version 1.1a" = a475834cb992bcb649c819ba83267b23
So you'd receive 1.1aa475834cb992bcb649c819ba83267b23

Truth is, you can't stop a dedicated person. Any keyhole can be opened. All you can do is make it a bit more complicated so it takes enough time (or effort) for them to give up, or be detected by authority.

The example i posted is a bit harder to spoof because:
a) they'd need to guess you used MD5 and not SHA1.
b) they'd need to figure out you're simply concatenating `<version code>` and `<version string>`
c) be able to wireshark it all along to figure it out. IF you're sending this via SSL, wiresharking goes down the drain and they'd simply have to use some other form of magic to read what's being sent during the login phase.

So yeah, use SSL for this.

Debugger update:

Debugger?? Nope, because you have the expected passphrase check on your server, and in case of a mismatch - you drop their connection. 
I hope you have a debugger check in your client, and to **NOT** run if a debugger is present; save it just for your own debug build; this is a release build we're talking about.

But regardless, to debug (and poke values like that) they need a couple of things:
1) debug symbols,
2) disassembled binary

I hope you're not handing them a non-stripped executable file with all the debug symbols still attached. Because otherwise you might just hand them the sourcecode as well.

The thing we're talking about is in C++, obfuscate before making, strip after making. That should take them a while to get anything meaningful with disassemblers, and debuggers won't help them much running stripped, obfuscated disassembled code if the code still builds.

But that's outside of the scope of the question, concatenating version with a hashed hardcoded passphrase is how you'd figure out their version on the server. Having a mismatch means they're trying to do something funky, so you can drop them.

Example of invalid versionString:

Receiving 1.1a4fd6b272e62e04dac52cab22e0643811 which is:
`1.1a` + hash("This is version 1.00") = 4fd6b272e62e04dac52cab22e0643811

Not that hard to implement (the first 4 letters are your versionCode, the rest is salt), and if the salt is good, check it against the expected versionCode for that salt. Additionally, make sure no file tampering was done by checking the checksum of the executable. And you should be safe no novice cracker/hacker is trying to pull something on you. But if he's really determined, give him a few months and he'll beat it :) or purchase the full game if wasting a few weeks on this don't change his mind.

Comment: Can't they just use a debugger and change the passphrase before it's hashed though? i.e. they could just replace 1.0 and "This is version 1.00" with 1.1a "This is version 1.1a"? Forgive me if this is a silly question.

Comment: Debugger? ? Nope, because you have the expected passphrase check on your server, and in case of a mismatch - you drop their connection. Even if they just change 1.00 to 1.1a, the hashed part wouldn't match, and you'd know he's up to no good.

Comment: I made a debugger-related update; but I'm kinda losing track of what we're trying to counter and prevent here. People running your client in a debugger environment and connecting to your server is a bigger issue than them spoofing their client version imho.

Comment: What I mean is an assembly-level debugger. Could they not just change both the passphrase values and the version number? But I suppose the point of your answer is that they couldn't sniff the packet in the first place to reverse the hash and find out how it's being assigned (by searching for it's hash in the debugger) because of using SSL?

Comment: Yes. The assembly-level debugger won't really be able to sniff out the passphrase that easily; code would have to be disassembled first. And down in ASM land, it would probably have to load the effecftive address of the hash into a register, before concatenating it to the easy-to-change version nuimber. That's the place whre he could place a breakpoint to change both. But if the passphrase was hardcoded in the binary fine, he wouldn't be able to change it without hexediting the file, right? And then the client's filesize and/or checksum wouldn't match so you could drop him as well.

Comment: And the best thing is, you're the guy that releases enw versions, you know the filesize/checksums of your next release before release. You're free to hardcode them in the server, and any client that mismatches on those two accounts has tampered the files.

Comment: Sweet, so a combination of SSL, the version check using a hashed passphrase, followed by a CRC check to prevent hexediting hopefully should be enough to thwart most people. The only way to get around this would be to modify values in memory as they are loaded, or find a way to bypass SSL to sniff and modify packets?

Comment: We can rely on the fact that SSL is unsniffable (and uncrackable), especially not by enthusiast crackers. The version check with salt, which is what the hashed passphrase is, is also a pretty safe thing - that, however, somewhat relies on security by obscurity rather than pure crypto safeness (because they don't know how you generated your passphrase, and how you're combining it with the versionCode) but is pretty safe due to the fact that hashes are kinda very hard to invert.

Comment: So yes, send the versionString thru a SSL, comprised of some combination of hashed passphrase and real versionCode, and attach your checksum in the same request. on the serverside, you can match the received versionString to your supported versionStrings, and accept or reject based on that. also reject&ban users with invalid versionString, checksum, or extracted versionCode.\

Comment: The new edit kinda gives you an idea of how those two things combine into verifyable keys; and checksum is there to guarantee no forging/hexediting has taken place.